# I am calling an action creator on the firestore code

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I get the `registeredUsers` array which is empty for the very first time. To register a user I want to check whether a  user has been registered or not. But When I call this function no data adds up.

Here's the image:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
export const userRegister = (user, programId) => async (dispatch) => {
  const data = {
    displayName: user.displayName,
    email: user.email,
    joinedAt: Date.now(),
    uid: user.uid,
  };
  // await console.log(data, programId);

  const docs = await db.collection("programs").doc(programId).get();
  const program = await docs.data();
    
  for (let i = 0; i < program.registeredUsers.length; i++) {
    if (user.uid !== program.registeredUsers[i].uid) {
      await db
      .collection("programs")
      .doc(programId)
      .update({
        registeredUsers: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data),
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the await for the docs.data().

But I would recommend to make such validations with the database rules and put your update call in a try catch. That way no one could add wrong data and if you self even try it wont be saved.

I don't know your use case but maybe just allowing users to create data and disallow editing and deleting. Also allowing them to add only under the uid that is they're user uid. If they can remove them selfe you can alloe them to delete data.